# Back to home page tabbar from deep level viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my tabbar. After i click on "Beer", will redirect to next VC[!
[image]

Now, i click on "HUAWEI..." items
[image]

Here, i click on more button on top right and finally, the menu with home button will popup.
[image: ![enter image description here]

I have a popup view controller as below:-
[image]

When I click on Home button (1st button), I will call a click function as below:-

```
- (void)toolsButtonClick1:(UIButton *)button
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSLog(@"click home - index 0");
    int index = 0;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
    [self.tabBarController.viewControllers[index] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSLog(@"click home - index 1");
}
```

Dismiss view controller is working fine and I can received NSLog but will not redirect to tab bar controller. Thank you.

Comment: i think you will get all time index 0,you face this problem than use tag propety

Comment: Hi JRB, if i use these code " [self.tabBarController.viewControllers[index] popToRootViewControllerAnimated..." in other modules, i can link it back to my home page. However, the result in this viewcontroller will hide the popup view and remain unchanged. What i expected is link back to home page.

Comment: You are calling `tabBarController` from present `ViewController` that is not in `tabBarController` so you have to put delegate where you get dismiss method and from there you call `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex`

Comment: Hi vp2698, can you show me some code sample over here? your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for change index of `tabBar`

```
//From where you presenting viewController
// In viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"ChangeIndex" object:nil];
```

Method where you can change index

```
-(void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"ChangeIndex"])
    {
       NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
       NSNumber* index = (NSNumber*)userInfo[@"indexToChange"];
       self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index.intValue;
     }
}
```

And your method

```
- (void)toolsButtonClick1:(UIButton *)button
{ 

   int index = 0;
   NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"indexToChange": @(index)};

   NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
   [nc postNotificationName:@"ChangeIndex" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi vp2698, thx for your explanation. However, I still no luck after applied code above in my project. I put "[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]... " and 2 methods in my ViewController but still the same. Any idea?

Comment: Is your viewcontroller is in tabbar from where you are presenting this view shown in image?

Comment: this viewcontroller is not from tabbar. Is from deep level viewcontroller. I wish to back to tabbar (home page).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be because you try to close the view controller at the same time as changing tab bar VC. You can serialize this by putting one of them into the other's completion block.

```
- (void)toolsButtonClick1:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSLog(@"click home - index 0");

    // Get presenting VC here because it will be gone in the completion handler
    UIViewController *presentingVC = self.presentingViewController;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        int index = 0;
        presentingVC.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
        [presentingVC.tabBarController.viewControllers[index] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        NSLog(@"click home - index 1");
    }];
}
```

Comment: Hi LGP, no luck, still remain unchanged after applied in my code.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that your current VC is modal, and therefore does not have the correct tabBarController? In that case you need to get your tabBarController from the parent VC. I have updated the code for this.

Comment: Hi LGP, still the same. My VC is 2 sub level under tabbarcontroller [index 1]. Now watever i clicked only will disappear the popup menu (as per image above).

Comment: Does that mean you have done two levels of `presentViewController`? In such case you will need dismiss twice also.

Comment: Do you mean i need to put  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; twice?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood you. Is your view hierarchy two levels deep, with tabBar at the first level? In that case my code proposal is valid, except I realise you must get a handle to the presenting view controller before dismissing it. I have updated the code above again. Please try it.

Comment: Hi LGP, i have changed my question on top with more screenshot provided. Perhaps you can help me on this. Sorry for any misleading explanation on top. Thx

Comment: Not sure I understand the relationsship between your view controllers. Did you try my latest suggestion? If it doesn't work, I need you to find the relationship between your view controllers. For example, you have three view controller, VC1 is parent to VC2, and so on. Otherwise it is hard to help you.